# How to order by name when getting users from firebase on Xamarin

Tags: c#, linq, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all of the users ordered by their FullName. The code gets all of the users if I don't add "OrderBy", but when I do add "OrderBy" no data returns.

```
public static async Task<List<Users>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return (await App.client.Child("Users").OrderBy("FullName")
          .OnceAsync<Users>()).Select(item => new Users
          {  
              Username = item.Object.Username,
              FullName = item.Object.FullName,
              UserType = item.Object.UserType
    }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: try using `OrderByChild`

Comment: `...).OrderBy(item => item.Object.FullName).ToList();` ?

Comment: `OrderBy(Item => Item.FullName).ToList();` worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static async Task<List<Users>> GetAllUsers()
{
    return (await App.client.Child("Users")
      .OnceAsync<Users>()).Select(item => new Users
      {  
          Username = item.Object.Username,
          FullName = item.Object.FullName,
          UserType = item.Object.UserType
}).OrderBy(Item => Item.FullName).ToList();
}
```